# Building a Unity exported Xcode project with LLVM and libc++

Tags: c++, xcode, unity-game-engine, llvm, libc++

I'm currently attempting to build an Xcode project exported from Unity with LLVM against libc++ (the LLVM C++ standard library). The project compiles and links against libstdc++ (the GNU C++ standard library).

If I include "/usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib" amongst the Other Linker Flags this resolves most of the issues but leaves one problem:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "__Z21UnityKeyboard_GetTextPSs", referenced from:
  __ZNK16KeyboardOnScreen7getTextEv in libiPhone-lib.a(iPhoneKeyboard.o)
```

It seems to be looking for the method void UnityKeyboard_GetText(std::string* text) as part of Keyboard.mm.

When I dump the symbols for Keyboard.o I get

```
00002900 T __Z21UnityKeyboard_GetTextPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE
000161c0 S __Z21UnityKeyboard_GetTextPNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE.eh
```

So the mangled names seem to be incompatible when I use libc++. Is there any possible of way of resolving this issue?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Did you find a way to solve this?